# AssertionError in torch_geometric.nn.GATConv

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, pytorch-geometric

I am trying to use graph attention network (GAT) module in `torch_geometric` but keep running into `AssertionError: Static graphs not supported in 'GATConv'` with the following code.

```py
class GraphConv_sum(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_ch, out_ch, num_layers, block, adj):
        super(GraphConv_sum, self).__init__()
        adj_coo = coo_matrix(adj) # convert the adjacency matrix to COO format for Pytorch Geometric
        self.edge_index = torch.tensor([adj_coo.row, adj_coo.col], dtype=torch.long)
        self.g_conv = nn.ModuleList()
        
        self.act = nn.LeakyReLU()

        for n in range(num_layers):
            if n == 0:
                self.g_conv.append(block(in_ch, 16))
            elif n > 0 and n < num_layers - 1:
                self.g_conv.append(block(16, 16))
            else:
                self.g_conv.append(block(16, out_ch))

    def forward(self, x):
        for layer in self.g_conv:
            x = layer(x=x, edge_index=self.edge_index)
            x = self.act(x)
            print(x.shape)
        return x[:, 0, :]
```

When I replace `block` with `GATConv` followed by a standard training loop, this error happens (other conv layers such as `GCNConv` or `SAGEConv` didn't have any problems). I checked the documentation and made sure the input shape was correct (same for other conv layers).

In the source code, there is this `assert x.dim() == 2, "Static graphs not supported in 'GATConv'"` part in the `forward` method but apparently the batch dimension will come into play in the forward pass and `x.dim()` would be 3. The input shape with batch dimension is [1024, 6, 200]. However, if I manually change the assert condition to `x.dim() == 3` the same error will still be raised as if the condition is not satisfied. I only have a high-level grasp of GAT so there might be something I am missing. Anyways, I have a few questions from this

- Are there any implementation errors possible from my side that caused this error?
- What is this assertion condition for? What is the static graph in this case?

I would appreciate any insights and help!! Thanks!

Comment: I only found in the [cheatsheet](https://pytorch-geometric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notes/cheatsheet.html) an explanation of static, that the GNN supports `x` with shapes `[batch_size, num_nodes, in_channels]`. However, GAT is not listed as static in contrast to GCN, which is static.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out due to the attention weight calculation, GATConv doesn't support multiple feature matrices and single edge_index. More info: https://github.com/pyg-team/pytorch_geometric/issues/2844

Comment: Is there a workaround?